# Highlighting command in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am running long builds with lots of data that I need to read through after each build. But I have to start from bottom up to reach to top and it takes lot of time as all the text looks same.

I was just wondering if it is possible that I can leave a command in terminal highlighted after it has been executed so that I can reach to it immediately and start downwards from there. i saw the colors supported by terminal but I think that won't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your PS1 shell variable with `tput` command so you can distinguish your commands from output:

```
$ export PS1="$(tput bold)$(tput setb 4)$PS1$(tput sgr0)"
```

Check 7th tip from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/

Comment: I have a (complex..) way in bash to color in blue the commands I type after the prompt, and have the resulting output of the command NOT blue (using trap). But it is probably overkill ^^

Comment: after putting it when I am copying something on my terminal than it is overwriting the command prompt completely though the execution is as normal. Well, it will solve my problem but just thought of sharing !

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- Use a terminal multiplexer, and only run that command there. The buffer will be exclusively for the build;
- Send the output to a file, and read the file after the build;
- Colour the output, as you say, although I'd consider this last. This will work as long as the build itself doesn't have any colour output:

```bash
colcmd() {
    tput setf 3
    "$@"
    tput sgr0
}
```

The number passed to `tput setf` defines which colour to use. See your terminal documentation for information about which colour codes correspond to which colours. `3` is usually yellow.

You can invoke coloured commands like so:

```
colcmd command args
```

Comment: thanks..it didn't really work for me but your suggestions have been gud learning experience ..